# Emscripten: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory when compiling for 32 bit

Tags: c++, emscripten

When trying to compile an existing C++ project with emscripten I got the following error:
`emmake make LINUX`

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0,
                 from src/abinitplugin.c:50:
/usr/include/features.h:367:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I am able to compile for LINUXAMD64, but I need it specifically 32-bit. How do I solve it?